# Removing word hyphenation with Perl

Tags: perl, hyphenation

I have this text:

```
Mary lives in a big ci-
ty near the most beati-
ful mountains in tne coun-
try.
```

How can convert it to:

```
Mary lives in a big city near the most beatiful mountains in tne country.
```

using perl

Comment: What do you want to do if your text contains words that *should* be hyphenated? e.g. "well-known" or "booby-trap"?

Comment: You'd want to limit this to those at endofline.

Comment: @tadman What prevents one of my examples from appearing at the end of a line?

Comment: This is one of those things where there's no way to do it automatically and perfectly, but you can get pretty close with automation and fix the exceptions manually.

Comment: @tadman Sure, you could fix the exceptions manually in this trivial example case, but that's not feasible for a long document. There's certainly no way to do it perfectly, but I would be interested to see a more intelligent solution than `s/-\n//`; I imagine it could be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/-\n//' file
```

**Switches**:

- `-i`: Edit `<>` files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Comment: `-i` is also great, does an in-place modification. Just be sure to have backups of your files before you trash them by accident.

Comment: Added documentation for `-i`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may need to take CRLF into consideration, especially when working with lesser operating systems (heheh). I try to make things as portable as possible.

```
s/-[\r\n]+//g
```

I put the '+' there, just in case there is an extra blank line between the hyphen and the rest of the text.